# How to add function to operate after successful mail sending event in MW WP Form?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

In MW-WP-Form, I created a form so clients can fill in their data and send it to me. I want their data will be saved into Google Sheets after sending mail successfully.

I had used `mwform_after_send_mw-wp-form-xxx` and `mwform_before_send_admin_mail_mw-wp-form-xxx`, but both of hooks will save data to Google Sheets even if sending mail failure.

Do I use them incorrectly? And how to fix that?

Information about MW-WP-Form's hooks here: https://mw-wp-form.web-soudan.co.jp/manual/action-hook/